# Function specialized with template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I need to make a specialization of my function with template class and have problem with "illegal use of explicit template arguments".

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass { /* ... */ }; // it can be any template class, eg std::vector

template <typename T>
void foo() { /* ... */ } // my template function which need a specialization

template<> 
void foo<int>() /* sth special for integers - it works */ }

template<template T> 
void foo<MyClass<T> >() /* sth special for template class with any parameter - it doesnt work :( */ }
```

Of course i can type a few specialization for all MyClass'es which i need to, but maybe it can be replaced with one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template specialization of function is not as flexible as specialization of `struct`: only full specialization is allowed. If you want to do partial specialization you need to wrap your `foo` function inside a `struct`:

```
template <typename T> class MyClass { };

template <typename T> struct Foo;

template <typename T> struct Foo { void foo() {}};

template<> struct Foo<int> { void foo() { } };

template<typename T> struct Foo< MyClass<T> > { void foo() {} };
```

And then instead of calling

```
foo<MyClass<...>>()
```

you call

```
Foo< MyClass<...> >::foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot partially speciallise a template function. There are discussions about removing that restriction though.

The advocated workarounds are:

1. Use a class template from the template function.
2. Wrap your function in a template class.

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_impl {
};
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    foo_impl<T>();
}

// And now specialize foo_impl as you want:

template<>
struct foo_impl<int> {
    foo_impl(){/* sth special for integers - it works */}
};
template<typename T>
struct foo_impl<myclass<T>> {
   foo_impl() {/* ... */}
};
```

If you wanted a return-value, you should use a member-function - probably `operator()` - instead of the ctor.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be using a base class

```
template<typename T> class MyClass;

class base {
private:
    template<typename T> friend class MyClass;
    base(); // Can't build a base object directly
};

template <typename T>
class MyClass : public base { 
public:
}; // it can be any template class, eg std::vector

template <typename T>
void foo() {
} // my template function which need a specialization

template<> 
void foo<int>() { /* sth special for integers - it works */ }

template<>
void foo<base>() { /* sth special for template class with any parameter - it doesnt work :( */ }
```

The above might also work in case you want a template parameter to your function. If you can wrap your function up I'd go with hivert's solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot of extra typing, but how about:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass { /* ... */ }; // it can be any template class, eg std::vector

template<typename T>
struct FooWrapper
{
    static void foo()
    {
       // default implementation
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct FooWrapper<MyClass<T>>
{
    static void foo()
    {
        // MyClass<T> implementation
    }
};

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
    FooWrapper<T>::foo();
}
```