# Partial specialization with class template

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23550519/1938163

and I'm wondering why the last line is a template struct's **partial specialization**

```
template<typename T> MyClass { public: };

template <typename T> struct Foo {void foo() {}};
template<> struct Foo<int> {void foo() { std::cout << "fooint";} };

// Why is this a partial specialization?
template<typename T> struct Foo< MyClass<T> > {void foo() {std::cout << "foo myclass";} };
```

I thought that a partial specialization consisted in replacing parameter arguments completely like the following

```
template <typename T, typename G> struct FooBar {};

template <typename G> struct FooBar<int, G>{}; // Partial specialization
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full specialization is when template parameters are all replaced by concrete types and the template parameter list is empty. `MyClass<T>` is not concrete; and

```
template<typename T> struct Foo<MyClass<T>> { ... };
```

it is still parametrized by `T`, and the template parameter list still contains `T`. For instance,

```
template<> struct Foo<MyClass<int>> { ... };
```

would be a full specialization of `Foo` that is more specialized than `Foo<MyClass<T>>`.