# Template explicit specialization in class using inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Yesterday I asked about template explicit specialization in class.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319518/function-with-template-specialization-in-class-without-wrapping-by-class).

Now I have the same purpose but now I wanna use inheritance to avoid code duplication. If I declare a function in the base class I cannot declare specialization of this function in the derived class.

My code:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    T fun()
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported template param");
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

template <>
bool Base::fun<bool>()
{
    return true;
}

template <>
float Derived::fun<float>()
{
    return 5.6f;
}

template <>
double Derived::fun<double>()
{
    return 5.684;
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    bool d_b = d.fun<bool>();
    float d_f = d.fun<float>();
    double d_d = d.fun<double>();
    char d_error = d.fun<char>();
}
```

VS code errors:

> use of inherited members is not allowed

g++

> error: template id "fun" for "float Derived :: fun ()" does not match any template declaration

Intel C++ compiler:

```
source/app.cpp:25:16: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'fun'
float Derived::fun<float>()
               ^
source/app.cpp:30:1: error: extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of variable 'fun'
template <>
^~~~~~~~~~~
source/app.cpp:31:17: error: redefinition of 'fun' as different kind of symbol
double Derived::fun<double>()
                ^
source/app.cpp:25:16: note: previous definition is here
float Derived::fun<float>()
```

If it is impossible in C++, please answer another question: what is a wide-known practice in c++ to do what I want. Before I used D language and one man says me I don't ask a question "Why" to myself. And instead, I just try to transfer D methods to C++. I agree. That's why I ask.

Maybe a better way is to ignore templates and declare separated functions? For example:

- funToBool()
- funToFloat()
- funToDouble()

Comment: Have you tried redeclaring:- class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    T fun();
};

Comment: @QuentinUK The redeclaration works because of name hiding, I think there should be another solution.

Comment: funToBool() etc could be declared virtual. These could then call template functions. Only worth it for complex templates.

Comment: @Ch3steR funToBool() etc are not virtual. An ordinary virtual function can call a template function.

Comment: @QuentinUK my bad! misread your comment.

Comment: @QuentinUK about virtual callback and then call template function I know. But I have a problem with that. Derived class A may accept only `float` & `bool`. Derived class B may accept only `double` & `bool`. Yes, I can set a callbacks buffer, fill that buffer in the derived class but it is an extra code in that place where no there isn't a reason to declare that code. I know you cannot override the virtual function but I don't try to override the function. I wanna declare specialization only.

Comment: @QuentinUK so, what is the best approach to reach my purpose? What would you do in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will compile if you add a public template definition of fun in Derived.
But that will probably not do what you want.
In particular `d.fun<bool>();` will not execute the implementation in Base, but the implementation in Derived.

You cannot specialize template functions in derived classes.

You also cannot use subtype polymorphism on template functions: template cannot be virtual.

You can achieve some type of static polymorphism using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Yes removing templates and working with separated functions would work (a.toX()...).

Another option is to work with overloads (i.e. passing a dummy argument or the destination variable and write different implementations).

Adding an example for the dummy argument solution as requested:

```
namespace TO {
    static const bool BOOL = false;
    static const double DOUBLE = 0.0;
    static const int INT = 0;
}

struct A {
 bool convert(bool dummy) {
     return true;
 }
};

struct B : public A {
    using A::convert; // important

    int convert(int dummy) {
        return 2;
    }

    double convert(double dummy) {
        return 3.0;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    std::cout << b.convert(TO::BOOL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.convert(TO::DOUBLE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.convert(TO::INT) << std::endl;
}
```

With this kind of solution there is a risk of implicit conversion when calling the function. toX() might be a safer option.

Comment: Can you tell about a dummy argument more? Like `0 = int`, `1 = float` ?